# How to remove the space between two fragments in android view pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can i remove the space between two fragment view in view pager.  I tried the following code, it's working in higher end devices, when i goes to lower end both fragement are merged.

```
private void screenDensityCheck(ViewPager pager)
    {

        float density = FragmentMainActivityHolder.this.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density;
        if (density >= 4.0)
        {
            pager.setPageMargin(-8 );
            Log.e("Mobile screen category===>>>>>>>>>", "xxxhdpi screen");
        } else if (density >= 3.0)
        {
            pager.setPageMargin(-21);
            Log.e("Mobile screen category===>>>>>>>>>", "xxhdpi screen");
        } else if (density >= 2.0)
        {
            pager.setPageMargin(-16);
            Log.e("Mobile screen category===>>>>>>>>>", "xhdpi screen");
        } else if (density >= 1.5)
        {
            pager.setPageMargin(-26);
            Log.e("Mobile screen category===>>>>>>>>>", "hdpi screen");
        } else if (density >= 1.0)
        {
            pager.setPageMargin(-26);
            Log.e("Mobile screen category===>>>>>>>>>", "mdpi");
        } else
        {
            pager.setPageMargin(-35);
            Log.e("Mobile screen category===>>>>>>>>>", "ldpi");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
      .getDisplayMetrics()); is this code helpful to you ??

Comment: @andruboy: shall i use this for all type screen resolution?

Comment: did you try this ?? just try it :)

Comment: @andruboy: sorry there is some space b/w the fragment one and two

Comment: @andruboy: dude, i set 8 instead of 4, it seems looking great, this change will cause any serious problem?

Comment: No but if it is helping you than do it :) should i post as answer ??

Comment: See i have posted as answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hey this code helps you :)

```
final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources() .getDisplayMetrics());
viewPager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
```