# How I can Remove the margin between two item in ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer, android-viewpager2

**XML**
I'm trying to remove the margin between viewPager2 items when I scroll the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/video_view">
    </VideoView>
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/exo_player">

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView>>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img"></ImageView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: When I run the code it looks like this]
[image: I want to make like this TikTok, no margin between items]

I' trying to make simple application like tiktok but this an issue I'm facing while scrolling my videos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the space between two fragments in android view pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908071/how-to-remove-the-space-between-two-fragments-in-android-view-pager)